# Hibernate OptimisticLocking(type = OptimisticLockType.DIRTY) not working

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a Grails/Groovy application and I want to use the OptimisticLockType DIRTY.
I made this annotations:

```
@DynamicUpdate(true)
@OptimisticLocking(type = OptimisticLockType.DIRTY)
@SelectBeforeUpdate
class OutboundMessage implements Message {
```

I log all the statements in the database (postgresq), but the query still looks like:
update outbound_message set version=$1, userdefined1=$2 where id=$3 and version=$4

It seems that the OptimisticLocking does not change anything.

I also tried without SelectBeforeUpdate

The code is just:

```
OutboundMessage msg = OutboundMessage.read(517)
msg.setUserdefined1(System.currentTimeMillis() + "")
msg.save(flush:true)
```

I followed this: https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-prevent-optimisticlockexception-using-hibernate-versionless-optimistic-locking/

Edit: I found a way to get rid of the version column on the update.

```
static mapping = {
    tablePerConcreteClass true
    dynamicUpdate true
    version false  
}
```

So it seems Grails ignores the annotations. I did not find a way to set the OptimisticLocking Type

Comment: The DynamicUpdate is working, it is just updating the changed fields